# Find most modified file extensions in SVN repository

Tags: svn, version-control, statistics, changelog

Given a SVN repository url how to find out which file extensions are the most touched.

Essentially I want to compare how much changes are done in JS versus C# code.

Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this (extension is anything after last dot, ignore paths where there is no dot at all):

```
svn log $url -v | grep '^   M \|^   A \|^   D \|^   R ' | grep '\.' | awk -F . '{print $NF}' | sed 's/:.*$//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -bgr
```

Example output (limited to 5 checkins):

```
svn log http://svn.code.sf.net/p/codeblocks/code/trunk/ -v --limit 5 | grep '^   M \|^   A \|^   D \|^   R ' | grep '\.' | awk -F . '{print $NF}' | sed 's/:.*$//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -bgr
     20 xpm
     20 bmp
     19 h
     19 cpp
     16 cbp
      7 am
      4 xml
      2 wxs
      2 rc
      2 in
      1 xrc
      1 workspace
      1 m4
      1 ac
```

Comment: Thanks @przno! It works! Just compared the result of my script with your command and got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get statistics using node.js script.

1. Switch to working copy folder and run the following command to get svn changes (for year 2015 in my case)

   svn log -v --xml  -r {2015-01-01}:{2015-12-31} > svn.log
2. Run the script

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
  xml2js = require('xml2js'),
  _ = require('lodash'),
  path = require('path');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

fs.readFile(__dirname + '/svn.log', function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error reading: ', err);
  }

  parser.parseString(data, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error parsing: ', err);
      return;
    }

    var paths = _.reduce(result.log.logentry, function(result, n, key) {
      var revisionPaths = _.map(n.paths[0].path, '_');
      result = result.concat(revisionPaths);
      return result;
    }, []);

    var statsByExtension = _.groupBy(paths, function(p) {
      return path.extname(p);
    });

    statsByExtension = _.map(statsByExtension, function(value, index) {
      return {
        ext: index,
        count: value.length
      };
    });

    statsByExtension = _.sortByOrder(statsByExtension, ['count'], ['desc']);

    _.forEach(statsByExtension, function(value, key) {
      console.log(value.ext, ' : ', value.count);
    });

    console.log('Done');
  });
});
```